# Which book construct the concept philosophy of Riemannian geometry as Arnold does but more elaborated?

Tags: reference-request, riemannian-geometry, book-recommendation, curvature, connections

In Riemannian geometry, the concept of covariant derivative/connection have at least 5 different equivalent definitions, as listed in Spivak's book. Most text books, like do Carmo' or S.S.Chern's et, start from koszul connection, then extend to other concepts.

But the most natural and beautiful way is what Arnold did in "Mathematial methods in classical mechanics". Using concept of geodesic, he defines paralle translation first, then Riemann curvature, then covariant derivative. But since the text is in appendix, he skips too many important proofs of many important conclusions. I'm not strong enough to fill them all.

I'm so eager to find a text book expanding the concept philosophy in Arnold's way, with all the elaborated details. But I cannot find the book. Can someone tell me which book satisfy my taste? Thank you so much.

--update--
@Deane 's comment reminds me that Arnold is not the only one who used geodesic as the start of the whole concept logic. Misner as well, in "Gravitation", where the geodesic is defined in a physical way, "free fall trajectory in curved spacetime". This is not rigorous from mathmatical point of view.

Comment: What Arnold explains is beautiful but requires a lot of work to make rigorous. He starts with but does not define or show the existence of geodesics. Given geodesics, his explanation of parallel translation on a Riemannian $2$-manifold is rigorous. He then explains what curvature is using the concept of holonomy. However, I do not see how to make his definition rigorous without using the covariant derivative. I think you should view his explanations as good intuitive descriptions of these concepts and not a path to doing everything rigorously.

Comment: Yes, I notice the def problem of geodesic as well. Arnold did not give the def but quoted do carmo's book "Differential geometry of curves and surfaces", but the thing is, do Carmo's book defines the covariant derivative first and then geodesic. There seems a circular statement by Arnold!

Comment: You can define a geodesic to be a curve which makes the action $S[\gamma]=\int_a^bg(\dot{\gamma},\dot{\gamma})\,dt$ stationary, so you don’t *need* to have defined the covariant derivative first. Once you do the variation in local coordinates, you’ll see exactly the local coordinate expression for the usual geodesic equation. But yea, it takes a little too much effort to develop things the way he describes (but it certainly is very nice and intuitive, and I wouldn’t be surprised at all if that’s how the development actually took place).

Comment: I think Arnold knew better than anyone else what he was doing and why he did not follow a Bourbakist approach. Like me you might realise some day that we need intuitive and rigorous approaches side by side to understand things well.